# Asterisk's customization for IVR and java command line program

Tags: java, asterisk

I need to get Asterisk's configured to react to dial in codes. A user calls, and enters a code. I need to make a few json calls, basically send a message to a java daemon running with the phone number of the person who called and the code that was typed in. I have looked everywhere in the dialplan configuration and found `EXEC` command, but I am afraid that too does not have any reference of integrating with a java based program/application.

Any advice at this moment will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number o ways you can do this. I would personally use an Java based AGI script. examples [here](http://www.asterisk-java.org/0.3/tutorial.html), [here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/asterisk-handle-calls-with-java-example) and [here](http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html)

But you can always use [System](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+System) to call a "java MyClass MyArgument" application in your classpath if that solution is best for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought AGI script only used to create dialplan's programmatically ?  I did not see the System call. Fantastic. thanks

Comment: You are welcome, I'm not very fond of the System call, I only use it when I don't have any other choice. Good luck!

Comment: The first and last link dont work. The one in the middle seems to give me what I need. Please correct the links above. I really want to see the other links aswell.

Comment: So what you are saying is, that in `HelloAgiScript.java` I can put my json thingy ?

Comment: Or run the daemon, or the whole IVR with the JSONs, depending on your needs, development time etc. Links working OK with Firefox and Chrome.